# Redirect rule creates a link with a double slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a link like this one: `www.mysite.com/article905.html/` to `www.mysite.com/article-title/` but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried adding a Redirect rule to the .htaccess like this one:

```
Redirect permanent /article905.html/ http://www.mysite.com/article-title/
```

But once applied, the system actually redirects me to `http://www.mysite.com/article-title//`

How can I avoid the double slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` for regex matching:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/article905\.html/?$ http://www.mysite.com/article-title/
```